# How can I generate a bitcoin.conf to synchronize with Sparrow?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin.conf, sparrow-wallet

Windows 10, external hard drive one TB, SSD

I accidentally deleted the bitcoin.conf file. Does anyone know how I can generate one, please? I’m trying to sync with Sparrow Wallet.

- I have looked online at every article, including on this site and there is only the suggestion to input `server = 1`. I've looked everywhere to see how to putaAll of the commands that I saw initially, which were many.
- Tried creating a document in "open config file" with "Server=1", but When trying "test your connection" it just stalls on "connecting to…"
- Their articles which say you can generate your own, but there is never any details—I've just started learning to code, so it will be sometime before I understand the theory

Comment: To make a bulleted list, you need to put a space after the asterisk. Did you see the topic I linked on your last question?

Comment: Yes, I saw your responses. Thanks. I also responded, but for some reason I can't see my response registered. Your diagnosis was correct, and thanks for your advice.

Comment: You had suggested an edit to my answer instead of posting a comment.